# How to plot the Fibonacci convergence to the golden ratio?

Tags: plotting, integer-sequence

I am interested to plot a convergence result of the Fibonacci sequence, namely $\frac{F(n+1)}{F(n)}\rightarrow\phi$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

So far I have created the following plot:

[image]

So, I am wondering if there is a way to connect the points but at the same time the points being visible.

Thank you.

Also, my code is this:

```
ListPlot[Table[Fibonacci[n + 1]/Fibonacci[n], {n, 20}], PlotRange -> {{0, 22}, {0, 2.5}},
Ticks -> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 15, 20}, {GoldenRatio}}, 
AxesStyle -> Directive[Arrowheads[0.03]], PlotStyle -> Directive[Black], 
TicksStyle -> Directive[Red, 15]]
```

Comment: Use `ListLinePlot` instead of `ListPlot` and add the option `Mesh -> Full`.

Comment: The next time you're producing ratios of Fibonacci numbers: `Ratios[Fibonacci[Range[20]]]`. For extra fun, replace, `Fibonacci[]` with `LucasL[]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A solution using `Epilog`:

```
ListLinePlot[
 t = Table[Fibonacci[n + 1]/Fibonacci[n], {n, 20}],
 PlotRange -> {{0, 22}, {0, 2.5}},
 Ticks -> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 15, 20}, {GoldenRatio}},
 AxesStyle -> Directive[Arrowheads[0.03]],
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Black],
 TicksStyle -> Directive[Red, 15],
 Epilog -> {PointSize[0.013], Point[Transpose[{Range[20], t}]]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Add the last two options

```
ListPlot[Table[Fibonacci[n + 1]/Fibonacci[n], {n, 20}],
 PlotRange -> {{0, 22}, {0, 2.5}},
 Ticks -> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 15, 20}, {GoldenRatio}},
 AxesStyle -> Directive[Arrowheads[0.03]],
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Black],
 TicksStyle -> Directive[Red, 15],
 Joined -> True,
 PlotMarkers -> Automatic]
```

[image]